# VLOOKUP help in Excel?

Tags: mysql, excel, vlookup

I have three columns of data, which look like:

```
05-May-15   05-May-15   0.006999933
05-May-15   06-May-15   0.006999933
05-May-15   05-Jun-15   0.008996562
05-May-15   06-Jul-15   0.008993128
05-May-15   05-Aug-15   0.006744264
05-May-15   05-Nov-15   0.006912941
05-May-15   05-May-16   0.007104633
05-May-15   05-May-17   0.006910929
05-May-15   06-Nov-17   0.007017292
05-May-15   07-May-18   0.00712202
05-May-15   05-Nov-18   0.007835916
05-May-15   06-May-19   0.008551509
05-May-15   05-Nov-19   0.009734602
05-May-15   05-May-20   0.010916848
05-May-15   05-Nov-20   0.011779622
05-May-15   05-May-21   0.012632521
05-May-15   05-Nov-21   0.013504069
05-May-15   05-May-22   0.014366506
05-May-15   07-Nov-22   0.014935518
05-May-15   05-May-23   0.0154865
05-May-15   06-Nov-23   0.016059181
05-May-15   06-May-24   0.016626256
05-May-15   05-Nov-24   0.017200193
05-May-15   05-May-25   0.017771865
05-May-15   05-Nov-25   0.018052656
```

The first is sorted from oldest to newest, the second is unsorted.

I need to pick up every instance where the difference between the first and second column is equal to one month. For example, I'd want to pick up the value in the 3rd column where the first column is 05 - May - 15 and the second column is 05 - June - 15, and do the same for 06 - May - 15 and 06 - June - 15, and so on for the rest of the series.

What VLOOKUP should I write to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What one are you actually using? Excel or MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is relatively simple because excel has a few built in functions to deal with adding/subtracting dates. In this case, I would use a combination of `=IF()` and `=EDATE()`.

The `=IF()` allows us to check if some logical test is true. In your case, we want to check if the difference between the date in column one and the date in column two is one month. Luckily, `=EDATE(m, n)` allows us to add or subtract exactly n calendar months from month 'm'. You're going to end up with a formula that looks somewhat like this:

`=IF(B1 = EDATE(A1, 1), C1, FALSE)`

Here, B1 is the second date, A1 is the first date, 1 is the number of months to add, C1 is the return value if the difference is one month, and FALSE is just the return value if it isn't exactly one month. The formula is concise, which is nice. You can change "FALSE" to whatever you want to return if the difference isn't one month, you just need to copy that formula down into a column, say column "D".

Answer (score 0):

Without vlookup: for example your table starts from "A1" cell. Then construct 4th column with formula

`D1 = AND(DAY(A1)=DAY(B1),YEAR(A1)+MONTH(A1)/12+1/12=YEAR(B1)+MONTH(B1)/12)`.

The column value will be TRUE for rows you need and false otherwise.